# Force creation of new memory object python

Tags: python, pointers, object

How do I forcefully create a new object (in this case a dictionary) in python? The following should explain my problem:

```
>>> class A():
...   def __init__(self, a={}):
...     self.a=a
... 
>>> id(A().a) == id(A().a)
True

>>> class A():
...   def __init__(self, a=dict()):
...     self.a=a
... 
>>> id(A().a) == id(A().a)
True

>>> class A():
...   def __init__(self, a={}):
...     self.a=copy.deepcopy(a)
... 
>>> id(A().a) == id(A().a)
False
```

As you can see, the first two methods give me a pointer to the same empty dictionary, which means if I modify the dictionary in one object, it gets modified in the other. The third method seems so "unclean" to me. Is there an alternative? I know I could also use copy.copy, but I prefer deepcopy, for exactly these reasons.

Comment: Related reading: [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/953482)

Comment: By the way, `id(A().a) == id(A().a)` is better written as `A().a is A().a`

Comment: I was debugging this visually with id(), that's why I used it. But you're right, it's more pythonic indeed. Will keep that in mind next time I post, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a common idiom:

```
def __init__(self, a=None):
  if a is None:
    a = {}
  ...
```

Comment: That quickly makes the constructor a lot bigger... But if there is no alternative, I guess I'll have to deal with it :p Thanks!

Comment: class A(dict):pass
       A().update(key='val')